# Printing elements of an array of arrays of primitives in Java using Arrays.deepToString( Object[] arr )

Tags: java

I'm having problems in printing the elements of an array of arrays of primitives in Java using the `Arrays.deepToString( Object[] arr )` method.  If I define `arr` as `int[][] T = { {0,1},{2,1} }`, then `T[0]` and `T[1]` are the 1D integer arrays [0,1] and [2,1] respectively, and therefore are Java objects.  For example, I thought that `Arrays.deepToString( T[0] )` would print [0,1]. But I get a compile time error, saying it cannot find the method.  Here is the program.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Test {
   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      int[][] T = {{0,1},{2,1}};
      System.out.println( "\nT[0] is " + Arrays.deepToString( T[0] ) + "." );
      System.out.println( "\nT[1] is " + Arrays.deepToString( T[1] ) + "." );
   }
}
```

I'm getting a compile time error, saying that it cannot find the symbol method `deepToString( int[] )` on lines 6 and 7 of the code.  Am I missing something obvious?  I've imported the correct class, java.util.Arrays, and I am calling the method according to the correct signature.

Please help.

Comment: Not that I don't totally agree with the answer you've chosen as the accepted one, but why did you first chose my answer, and then decided to invalidate it and chose another which sais the exact same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sandeep, Arrays.deepToString is expecting an array of Objects, you are passing in an array of integer primitives.

You need to change your two dimensional array from using int primitives, to Integer Objects. This way auto-boxing takes care of the conversion from int to Integer when creating the array.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Test {
   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      Integer[][] T = {{0,1},{2,1}};
      System.out.println( "\nT[0] is " + Arrays.deepToString( T[0] ) + "." );
      System.out.println( "\nT[1] is " + Arrays.deepToString( T[1] ) + "." );
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I thought even arrays of primitives were objects in Java.  For example, they have a `length` attribute that you can see.

Comment: An Array of primitives is an Object, specifically the actual Array is an object, not the contents of the Array.

Answer (score 0):

deepToString() accepts arrays of Objects, not primitives. Try:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
          Integer[][] T = {{0,1},{2,1}};
          System.out.println( "\nT[0] is " + Arrays.deepToString( T[0] ) + "." );
          System.out.println( "\nT[1] is " + Arrays.deepToString( T[1] ) + "." );
       }
```

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString%28java.lang.Object[]%29